# Go import scope lookup for protobuf types

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I'm building a transpiler and need to understand the protobuf/go scope lookup system. I've been trying to google the docs and finding no luck.

Q: Is there a shared package scope lookup that you can do when importing Types in Go/protobufs?

Here is the example that I'm questioning:

proto1:

```
package cosmos.crypto.keyring.v1;
...

message Ledger {
    hd.v1.BIP44Params path = 1;
}
```

proto2:

```
package cosmos.crypto.hd.v1;
message BIP44Params {
    ...
}
```

There are two syntaxes I've seen that do make sense so far:

#### full scope

```
message Ledger {
    cosmos.crypto.hd.v1.BIP44Params path = 1;
}
```

Or I’ve also seen versions like this

#### completely unscoped

```
message Ledger {
   BIP44Params path = 1;
}
```

#### partially scoped?

But the style I'm seeing is partially scoped

```
message Ledger {
    hd.v1.BIP44Params path = 1;
}
```

Is the reason they leave off the `cosmos.crypto` because these two packages share `cosmos.crypto` in the root of their package name?

Or is it a more generic scope lookup based on the import?

Any insight or reading links appreciated :)

Comment: I'm researching the source and finding some info here https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc#L4353-L4426

Comment: more "docs" that I found: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc#L3798-L3812

Comment: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc#L4353-L4426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully get the question but I will try to answer. Let me know if you need me to change that.

This is a combination of both. You need to have the package and import the .proto file. Let me explain. If you have two file define like this:

#### proto1.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package cosmos.crypto.keyring.v1;

message Ledger {
    hd.v1.BIP44Params path = 1;
}
```

#### proto2.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package cosmos.crypto.hd.v1;

message BIP44Params {}
```

trying to compile will tell you that `"hd.v1.BIP44Params" is not defined`. This is because the `proto1.proto` is not aware of other definitions. Now, if you `import "proto2.proto";` in the `proto1.proto`, it will be aware of the `BIP44Params` definition and will notice the package definition.

With this package definition, it will be able to access the following type definition:

- `cosmos.crypto.hd.v1.BIP44Params` - which is pretty self explanatory
- `hd.v1.BIP44Params` - because the two package matches before the `hd` part.

but it should be able to access:

- `BIP44Params` - because there is no such type defined in `cosmos.crypto.keyring.v1` package

Hope that's clear

Comment: thanks for the simplified answer! I ended up reading the source code here, and got a detailed answer if you're curious: `DescriptorBuilder::LookupSymbolNoPlaceholder`

Comment: which lives here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/6da9b69efe369f3b17087c7d4e142503f05fb04a/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc#L4353-L4426